# Unable to set nested json value via ConfigurationSettings

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, configurationsection

I have a class in Package XYZ say:

```
public class Temp
{
    string a;
    string b;
    string c; 
 }
```

Another class in same package:

```
public class Other
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public Temp temp {get;set;}
}
```

Now the values for `Temp` and `id` variables for class Other come from `appsettings.json` of another project which looks like:

```
...some settings
"Other":{
  "id":2
 "Temp":{
  "a":"Hey",
  "b":"Hello",
  "c":"Bye"
 }
},
...rest of the settings
```

Now, in the package extension class, I am trying to set the values as:

```
id = configuration.GetValue<int>("Other:id"); // 2 here
Temp = configuration.GetValue<Temp>("Other:Temp");  //null here
```

Not sure why this value isn't get set.

I tried: `Temp = configuration.GetSection("Other:Temp")` but that can't convert it to instance of type Temp.

Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to parse small temp in json, because your property is like 'temp'

Comment: I didn't get that @Bharat, can you please elaborate?
Thanks.

Comment: what I mean is udpate your json Temp key with small temp and then retrieve it with Temp = configuration.GetValue<Temp>("Other:temp");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by adding :

```
Temp = new Temp
{
   a = configuration.Get<string>("Other:Temp:a"),
   b = configuration.Get<string>("Other:Temp:b"),
   c = configuration.Get<string>("Other:Temp:c")
}
```